# Cannot load caret library

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, r-caret

I'm trying to load the caret library using Jupyter Notebook but I am obtained the following:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'caret' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace 'recipes' 0.1.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.1.10 is required
Traceback:

1. library(caret)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

I think I have all the needed packages:

```
install.packages('lsr')
install.packages('e1071')
install.packages('MASS')
install.packages('Metrics')
install.packages('ggplot2')
install.packages('dplyr')
install.packages('lattice')
install.packages('caret')
```

What I'm missing/doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message implies that you need to exit your current session, install a more recent version of the recipes package and then try to load or perhaps re-install  caret. What about that is that not obvious? (On Windoze and Macs you may need to set dependencies=TRUE to get a complete installation or if failing to get informative error messages about missing or out-of-date packages. That much might not be obvious.)

Comment: The relevant part of the error message is this line: `namespace 'recipes' 0.1.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.1.10 is required`. What this means that your version of the library `recipes` is not recent enough. You need to update it, and possibly others to be able to use `caret`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by restarting R.

Otherwise, I would suggest to check your R version and, in case, update it.
I have the version 4.0.5 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
packageVersion('recipes')  #  0.1.5
remove.packages("recipes")
install.packages("recipes")
packageVersion('recipes')  # 0.1.10   

##

I had the sort of issue such as recipes but with vstrs:
>library(caret)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.5.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.6.0 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘caret’ was built under R version 4.2.3 "


I have tried:
install.packages("caret",repos = "http://cran.r-project.org", 
dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))
It didn't solve the problem.
##
    Another solution is to download 'caret' manually:
1/ on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html
download caret_6.0-94.zip
2/ on R check where are your library
 .libPaths()
#"C:/Users/XXXX/Lib/R/library"
3/ Unzip your caret_6.0-94.zip that you will put in this repertory.
##
    install.packages("vctrs")
    packageVersion('vctrs')    # check version
    remove.packages("vctrs")   # remove old version
    try install.packages("vctrs",repos = "http://cran.r-project.org") if still issue:
go to 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vctrs/index.html
download vctrs_0.6.1.zip 
and put the unzip package in 
 .libPaths()   # to check where to put it
#"C:/Users/XXXX/Lib/R/library"
install.packages("vctrs")
library(vctrs)
packageVersion('vctrs')
#6.0.1

and same for each package with errors


Hope it works
```

Comment: It's not the installation method causing the issue, it's caused by an outdated version of `recipes` conflicting with the `caret` install. Please refer to the comments on the OP for clarification.